# Oracle 11g count distinct products group by user

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table with following fields

| ID | PRODUCT | STATUS | USERID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 10 | 01-01-2023 |
| 2 | 101 | 1 | 10 | 01-01-2023 |
| 2 | 102 | 2 | 10 | 01-01-2023 |
| 3 | 100 | 2 | 20 | 02-01-2023 |
| 4 | 102 | 1 | 30 | 02-01-2023 |
| 4 | 100 | 1 | 10 | 03-01-2023 |

Desired output

Distinct product scan by each userid between 01-01-2023 to 03-01-2023 and count by status for each user

| USERID | PRODUCT SCAN | STATUS1 CNT | STATUS2 CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 30 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: And what is the issue? Please show your current code and describe what is wrong with it. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Your requirement should be literally translated into the SQL code if you match your verbs with the equivalent verbs of SQL

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)`.

**Query**

```
select userid, count(distinct product) as productScan
from table_name
where date between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-03'
group by userid;
```

Comment: Thanks working can you please check the output i edit to count status as well by user.THnaks in advance